# IdentityServer returns BadRequest invalid_grant

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor, identityserver4

The following .NET Core method returns BadRequest error:invalid_grant
However not always, only in the middle of a session - not sure what else is needed. The request is made from a Blazor App:

```
private async Task<TokenResponse> RefreshAccessToken()
    {
        string authority = _configuration.GetValue("Authority", "url...");
        using (HttpClient serverClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient())
        {
            var discoveryDocument = await serverClient.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(authority);
            var refreshToken = _tokenProvider.RefreshToken;
            using (HttpClient refreshTokenClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient())
            {
                TokenResponse tokenResponse = await refreshTokenClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(
                    new RefreshTokenRequest
                    {
                        Address = discoveryDocument.TokenEndpoint,
                        RefreshToken = refreshToken,
                        ClientId = "client id ...",
                        ClientSecret = "secret ..."
                    });

                return tokenResponse;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the request message:
[image]

Comment: what is your refresh token's expiry? This is most likely because of `Using expired refresh tokens`

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are implementing your own refresh logic?  The IdentityServer developers created a Nuget package to help simplify token management.  [IdentityModel.AspNetCore](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.AspNetCore).  Wanted to mention it because I went down the same path until I found the library.

Comment: What does the log in IdentityServer say?